# Use array of pipes to change value

Tags: angular, templates, pipe

I would like to keep pipes in a configuration array and execute them in the defined order.

For example the config looks like this:

```
const pipes = [ 
{
   pipe: PipeA,
   input: ...
},
{
   pipe: PipeB,
   input: ...
},
{
   pipe: PipeC,
   input: ...
},
]
```

And by executing *something like* `{{ value | MAGIC }}` it will be transformed to `{{ value | pipeA | pipeB | pipeC }}`

Does it even possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You need to inject dynamically the Pipe and then call the `transform` method. But you also can create a magicPipe that call pipeA and then pipeB etc...

Comment: I think you should come with a more concrete example, because what you want is not possible, but if you show better what you have and what you are trying to achieve, there may be other ways